# Fast QPixmap scaling

Tags: c++, qt, zooming, scaling, qpixmap

I develop a browser-like application, where the canvas has large height and "ordinary" width, something like 1024x999999. I display a picture using 512 cached **QPixmap** blocks (1024x128), re-using them to display newly drawing areas. So if user scrolls around some given area of the large image, CPU is not busy, the cached blocks is used. So, this is how my engine works, briefly.

Want to implement a zoom. Don't know - smooth or discrete (x2, x3, x4...). Performance questions:

- Is there any effective way to scale **QPixmap** on-the-fly in **paintEvent()** without allocating too much memory?
- or maybe i should think about "zoom-layers" that cache zoomed picture for different zoom factors? But this makes smooth zooming impossible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation, you'll see that the `paintEvent` in fact receives a `QPaintEvent` object. This object has a getter method named `region()` that returns a `QRect` detailing the region to be repainted.

```
void QWidget::paintEvent ( QPaintEvent * event )
{
  QRect region = event->region();
  ...
}
```

So... you just need to repaint the part of the widget that is **exactly inside** that rectangle.

For your application, I recommend to calculate which image or images are within the rectangle, and redraw them accordingly, but only those images.

For the zoom part, Qt has *optimized* the way images are painted in `QPainter` objects if images are `QPixmap` objects. Or so they say...

So, you can write inside the `paintEvent()` method something like:

```
QPainter painter(this);
...
painter.drawPixmap(pos_x, pos_y, width, height, pixmap);
...
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Yes, thank you! QPixmap is optimized for screen output, i use it and can draw fullscreen window almost with zero CPU cost. But zooming methons i've seen so far is returning NEW QPixmap object. I thought it would not be nice to make copies in every paintEvent().

Comment: You don't need to make new `QPixmap` instances if you already have them calculated in some array, but if they need to be calculated on the fly, then yes, you must instantiate new `QPixmap`s. Please accept the answer if that was what you needed.

Comment: I have them calculated in some array, but only for zoom level=1. So should i create 10 another arrays for 10 another zoom levels? :)

Comment: If they are cached in an array with zoom factor 1, as you only have to draw those that are visible, I don't think it would be wise having in mind that it would consume a lot of RAM.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the answer (my poor english). You say that i have to scale QPixmaps on the fly in paintEvent() depends on zoom factor value?

Comment: What I meant is that if you want a 2x zoomed image, you simply put `painter.drawPixmap(x, y, 2*w, 2*h, pixmap)`, being `w` and `h` the original width and height of the pixmap.

Comment: O, i didn't knew about that feature (-;